# Sigma calculator

Tags: c++

How could I improve this sigma calculator library, so it is easier to use? For example, the polynomial class is clumsy because I am not able to pass just a list of `term`s to the constructor, I must use the `addTerm` function instead. Also when passing values to the `term` constructor it's unclear which argument is the coefficient and which is the exponent, unless you think about it a little.

```
#include <list>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

class term {
    int coef;
    int exp;
public:
    term(int coef, int exp) : coef(coef), exp(exp) { }
    double substitute(int valForX)
    {
        return coef * pow(valForX, exp);
    }
};
class polynomial {
    std::list<term> poly;
public:
    polynomial() { }
    void addTerm(const term &t)
    {
        poly.push_back(t);
    }
    double substitute(int valForX)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (auto it = poly.begin(); it != poly.end(); ++it)
            sum += it->substitute(valForX);

        return sum;
    }
};

double sigma(int start, int end, polynomial rule)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
        sum += rule.substitute(i);
    return sum;
}
double sigma(int start, int end, term rule)
{
    polynomial p;
    p.addTerm(rule);
    return sigma(start, end, p);
}
```

Also I feel the performance of the `substitute` calls are slow, because there are many of them being done.

Comment: How important is accuracy to you? If it plays only a minor role, you could maybe improve the performance of substitute by replacing your calls to `pow` with simple multiplication while memoizing the intermediate results, i.e. calculate `x^2` and use it, then calculate `x^3` by simply multiplying with `x` etc. Of course, this is only beneficial if you have a lot of adjacent powers.

Comment: @BenSteffan I will implement that. I'll do a `switch` on the `coef` to select if its one, two, or three. If its bigger than that, then i will call `pow`

Comment: No, that is not really what I meant. Just calculate adjacent coefficients by multiplying by `x`. For example, if you have coefficients 46, 47 and 48, calculate 46 by using `pow`, then calculate 47 by multiplying 46 with x, then calculate 48 by multiplying 47 by x.

Comment: @BenSteffan, adding terms with the same exponent together will make the task very easy! But without it, the approach will require some sort of storage with linear complexity in memory.

Comment: @BenSteffan Comments are for seeking clarification to the question, and may be deleted. Please put all suggestions for improvements in answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is really straightforward and easy to understand. Some thoughts:

## Making It Easier To Use

You ask, "How could I improve this sigma calculator library, so it is easier to use?" You talk about the fact that a user of this class will have to call `addTerm` repeatedly to make use of it. There are a few other options, though it's not clear that they are better.

1. Write a factory function that uses [variadic arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). It might look something like this:

```
polynomial* makePolynomial(int count, ...)
{
    polynomial* result = new polynomial;
    
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        result->addTerm(va_arg(ap, term));
    }
    va_end(ap);
    
    return result;
}
```

2. Have a constructor or factory function that takes a string that you parse. It could be in some format like `"c1,e1;c2,e2;"` etc. In this case the `c` variables would be coefficients and the `e` variables would be exponents. Parsing strings can be error prone, so I tend to dislike this particular solution, but it does make it nice for the caller.

In terms of clarifying which argument to the constructor is the coefficient and which is the exponent, I think you've done what you can. You put them in the order people are used to writing them and have named them appropriately. I don't see anything else you could do unless you want to get ridiculous and make a `coefficient` type and an `exponent` type. That seems like overkill for what are `int` arguments. I wouldn't recommend that.

## Improving Performance

To know for sure why it's slow (or even *if* it's slow) you should profile it and see where the slowdowns occur. I can make an educated guess, but it's just that – a guess. The `substitute` method in `term` is doing 2 things that are often a performance problem: 1) (implicitly) casting from `int` to `double`, and 2) calling `pow()`.

You can completely remove the casts by making `coef` and `exp` be `double`. You can even leave the constructor as only taking `int` if you want to limit them to being integer values. But internally, they'd be stored as `double` to make the calculation faster. This way if you call `substitute` repeatedly with the same `term` it doesn't do the conversion multiple times. (If you only call it once, then you haven't improved performance – you've only changed where the slow code happens. Now part of it happens during construction.)

As for `pow`, since you know that `exp` is always an integer value, you could instead write a loop. I'd do some experiments to see at which point it's no longer a win because I'm sure looping a thousand times to calculate `x^1000` is probably slower than just calling `pow(x, 1000.0);`

## Idiomatic C++

If you're using C++11 or later, I'd change the `substitute()` method to use the newer [ranged loop](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) structures:

```
for (auto nextTerm : poly)
{
    sum += nextTerm->substitute(valForX);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't I make the variable argument list be in the `polynomial` constructor itself?

Comment: I haven't done that before. If I recall correctly, you can't do it with normal constructors, only with template constructors. But I could be wrong. I tried looking it up, but all searches only turned up variadic template constructors, unfortunately.

Comment: @stackptr, variable argument list is a C feature. I strongly advise you to not use it. Something like template parameter pack would be ok, but iterator based and initializer list based solution is a standard one.

Comment: @user1118321, the last one would be `std::accumulate` call with a lambda. Might be longer, but I believe it might be more readable.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense too! Good call!

Answer (score 5):

### Architecture overview

Well, it started good, but turned bad. **Very bad**.

First of all, lets kick off from important things

### Debunking myths

> I am not able to pass just a list of terms to the constructor

This one is *especially* wrong. One can just have

```
template <typename InputIterator>
polynomial(InputIterator first, InputIterator last):
                                        poly(first, last)
{}
```

This will allow constructing the polynomial from *any* iterator based container.

> when passing values to the term constructor it's unclear which argument is the coefficient and which is the exponent,

This is not so relevant these days, but tired programmer can still do a mistake or thousand of them.

> Also I feel the performance of the substitute calls are slow, because there are many of them being done.

This is hard to prove, as there are no facts. On the one hand, we have `std::pow()`, which does all of the precision caring stuff, on the other hand, we have traversal of a linked list.

### Possibly better architecture

`term` class is the correct step. Though everything else after that is just bad abstraction. Lets think about current abstraction:

- `term` - encapsulates a *term*. Has a member function to substitute a value. May be not entirely nitpick proof, but is good already.
- `polynomial` - encapsulates a container of `term`s and provides operation to substitute a value on all of the `term`s. But why does it take ownership of `term`s? Why are they bound to `std::list` which has bad traversing performance? C++ doesn't give performance, it gives *control* over performance. And now performance is certainly not first class citizen of the code.

Now, after having some ideas about where did it get wrong, lets create a new abstraction:

- let `term` be a `struct` of `const int`s (for now).
- Make a function which would substitute a value into `term`, e.g. a *free function*.
- Make iterator based algorithm to perform the substitution on a range of `term`s. This way people will have ability to choose what their container is, or you can directly substitute from a stream. It is a simple `std::accumulate` call with a lambda.
- Transform the `sigma` function into iterator based function. Do note that due to multipass requirement the function won't be able to do it directly from the stream, but anything slightly stronger and higher like ForwardIterator will do.

### Performance

We've dealt with the abstraction, now lets consider performance. What mathematically clean optimizations can we do? (they are going in first as they are easier to reason about in most of the cases)

1. Add all terms that have the same exponent.

   Now this one will require a standalone `polynomial` class, probably containing something like `std::unordered_map`.
2. Memorize previous powers (as Ben said)
3. Perform some other trickery I'm unaware of

Then, I believe, the last thing is to look at what compiler made of it, and see if there are things to improve. Do note though, *always benchmark*, because sometimes ignorance, which we all have to some extent, might play a very bad game with you.

Comment: How exactly would this kind of constructor work? `template <typename InputIterator>
polynomial(InputIterator first, InputIterator last): poly(first, last){}` Like this? `polynomial poly { range.begin(), range.end() };`

Comment: @stackptr, you call it like that, yes. But also `polynomial poly{std::istream_iterator<term>{std::cin}, {}};` to extract from a stream or anything else that is single pass. Do not forget to add initializer list constructor, which should just delegate to iterator based one.